# What is the purpose of a makefile?

Tags: c

What does it do? Do you just run make on the command line? Is the makefile just like a list of commands to execute and at the end of the make command you have a bunch of executable files?

Comment: I read part of the wiki page. I didnt really understand it.

Comment: You will find reply to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202803/linux-makefile-structure-and-documentation) quite useful.

Comment: Just read the whole thing still confused.

Comment: Thanks Milind I'll give it a read.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux Makefile structure and documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202803/linux-makefile-structure-and-documentation)

Comment: `I didnt really understand it` what part of it do you not understand? That limits the range of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is essentially just a list of instructions. The purpose of a makefile is to be easily build an executable that might take many commands to create (which would be a pain to compile over and over again manually).

Comment: Props to Milind who linked to another question and to Freddy who posted a very helpful [link](http://mrbook.org/blog/tutorials/make/).

Comment: Also props to you Marth. You gave a brief but useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

The answer above is pretty correct, but misses an important point: makefiles are intelligent, they are meant to run only the needed commands, not all. This is done with the concept of dependencies between items, like:

> to generate A from B, it is necessary to run (for example) "cc -o A B".

These rules/dependencies can be cascaded (to have A you must use B; to have B, you must use C+D+E, to have D you must do ...)

If your *project* is structured in many files, a makefile will (normally) recreate the objects whose dependencies are changed, *not* all the objects.

Think of a C project split in 10 files. You modify one, say "main.c" and then want to test the project. With Makefile, only "main.c" gets recompiled and then the final executable gets linked. Without a Makefile, perhaps all the 10 files would get recompiled.